# Google Developer API keys & YouTube API

Tags: ruby, api, oauth, youtube, google-api

I started a web based dev project using YouTube and when I signed up for the API all I received was a client ID and email ID. However in the Ruby example text for calling the data API it states:

```
  def initialize(scope)
    credentials = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
    @authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
      :authorization_uri => credentials.authorization_uri,
      :token_credential_uri => credentials.token_credential_uri,
      :client_id => credentials.client_id,
      :client_secret => credentials.client_secret,
      :redirect_uri => credentials.redirect_uris.first,
      :scope => scope
```

I don't know where to go to grab these credentials. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since YouTube is now Google-account-based, these credentials need to be acquired on the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) (pick the YouTube Data API), and you'll have to initiate the normal Google sign-in process. Your client_id and client_secret are generated when you create a new application on the console, your redirect_uri is set based on your application structure.

While Signet has a nice OAuth2 module associated with it, I've found Omniauth to be very easy to work with (and you can still use it in conjunction with Signet). If you don't need to customize the sign in process, Omniauth puts most of this in a black box (it's very high-touch), and handles token refreshes, etc. for you. I might use the [Omniauth Google strategy](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) to get your tokens, then the [Google Ruby client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) to make requests.